# Adding assembly to toolbox, which depends on old version of other assembly?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, firebird, toolbox, assembly-binding-redirect

In VS2015 I'm trying to add the assembly Eco.Persistence.Firebird to the designer toolbox. It has a dependency on FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient version 2.6.5.0, which is very old. I want to use the current version of this assembly, i.e. 4.10.0.0 and have installed it both in Windows using the Windows installer and in the VS project using nuGet.

I've added both assemblies to the GAC using gacutil.

But when I try to add Eco.Persistence.Firebird to the designer toolbox (using "Choose Items..." and "Browse..." on the ".NET Framework Components" tab, the dialog responds with an error saying it can't load the assembly because it can't resolve one or more of its dependencies.

I know there is such a thing as "binding redirect", and I suspect that I need to add that somewhere. Is that right? If so, where and how?

Comment: have you tried my way? Does this work?

Comment: We found that Eco.Persistence.Firebird was an old version in the NuGet package, so we're waiting for the developer to fix that. Once that's in place we'll try your suggestion, which I think will work unless there's some kind of incompatibility between FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient versions.

Comment: Found out now that the framework provider has source published for Eco.Persistence.Firebird, so we'll probably build it for the current version of FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient instead of using a binding redirect. Might give that a go anyway just to see if it works...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`":

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" publicKeyToken="3750abcc3150b00c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.10.0.0" newVersion="4.10.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

this should make VS to use the latest FB provider version.